# Debian freezes after some time

Tags: linux, debian, freeze

I have Debian Server, which apparently freezes after some time. When this happens the only way is to hard shutdown it by long pressing the power button. I don't know where to look for the reason of this to fix it. Unfortunately I have to fix this because I can't install the Debian completely new (the server is running some important stuff).

Some initial information:

- x86_64 architecture
- SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27)
- kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64

The server is currently running in a Hadoop cluster and that's it. I looked into the `/var/log/syslog` and there are only entries from the Hadoop starting, and after that it only renews via DHCP in intervals of 300 seconds.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE! For starters, you could poke around in `/var/log/`, and show us the interesting bits (errors, warnings). We can't tell you what's wrong without knowing what your system is doing, you need to include more information in your question. Tell us what the server is _supposed_ to be doing, and _where_ it freezes.

Comment: Does the frozen machine answer to ping, can you toggle the Caps-Lock led on the keyboard, is there anything on the text console?

Comment: @FerencWágner no the machine does not answer to ping. The next time i am there i will try if the keyboard responds. But like i said the only thing i can do to reset it is to press the power button for a long time so the power supply resets.

Comment: It sounds like your kernel crashes. You'd need console logs to debug that, preferably from a serial console. Or you can switch to a newer kernel from backports, if you can live with frequent kernel upgrades.

Comment: @FerencWágner i was now just right there when it happened. The system was completely frozen and i was not able to toggle caps-lock.

Comment: Definitely a hard kernel crash then. Might be caused by hardware instability (failing part/overheating) or a kernel bug. Were you working on a graphical desktop? If not, did you see a kernel backtrace on the screen? I'd try replacing the kernel and, if that doesn't help, the hardware (unless you can capture some kernel console logs with concrete information).

Comment: You can also try booting and running a memory test for a day or so to detect hardware issues. Install and use the _memtest86_ or the _memtest86+_ package. Your service will be down during the test, since these replace the operating system to be able to test all the memory.

Comment: @FerencWágner thank you for your answer, i already did the memory test with memtest86, but nothing was found. I decided to speak to the people working on the machine too and we agreed that it probably will be the best to install the system completly new. But thanks to you i learned about backports wich i will still try beforehand.

Comment: @Talto - did re-installing help? I am having similar issue.

Comment: @lifeofguenter i cannot really say. I installed the latest ubuntu version and now the system is running fine. So i am not sure if it was debian or something different.

Answer (score 1):

Use htop to find out any unnecessary processes that may be hogging up cpu time.

Install:

sudo apt-get install htop

As a bonus, you can increase the priority from within htop for your Hadoop software so that it will run more smoothly.