# Debian 10/Buster crashing after days of usage

Tags: debian, gnome3, desktop, crash

I am using Debian 10/Buster on my desktop with Gnome3. It is working quite well but after a couple of days it will just crash.

The PC is still on, but the keyboard is unresponsive and the display won't wake up.

After doing a hard-reboot I can not find anything useful in the logs:

```
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 dbus-daemon[612]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=614 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 dhclient[988]: bound to 192.168.1.58 -- renewal in 281 seconds.
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 dbus-daemon[612]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlo1]: new request (1 scripts)
May  3 06:04:35 x5-452 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlo1]: start running ordered scripts...
May  3 06:04:45 x5-452 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
May  3 06:57:43 x5-452 systemd-modules-load[361]: Inserted module 'lp'
May  3 06:57:43 x5-452 systemd-modules-load[361]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
May  3 06:57:43 x5-452 systemd-modules-load[361]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
```

Questions:

- is anyone experiencing similar?
- how can I debug the crash better?

Hardware:

- Intel i3-8100T (BIOS with latest firmware)
- 32GB RAM
- SSD
- no extra graphic card

Kernel: `Linux x5-452 4.19.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.28-2 (2019-03-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Does Ctrl + Alt + F1 take you out of the GUI to a terminal screen? Can you `ssh` in to the PC (from another device on your LAN)?

Comment: See the comments under https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/512774/119808 for more tips.

Comment: @roaima updated question with kernel info. No keyboard combination works (so unfortunately its not just the gui that crashed, but seems like complete PC).

Comment: I initially thought this was some sleep that was happening. So I tried disabling via systemd, and also found out that my BIOS had a setting which disabled wake-up from USB (e.g. keyboard?) - after enabling that, it seemed to have fixed it.

But unfortunately after a couple of days uptime it crashed again during sleep. If this is very uncommon I am guessing this might be a Hardware issue somewhere. All parts are new except the CPU - but there are no obvious signs (like overheating).

Comment: Have you solved this issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely answer your first question - I'm experiencing the same issue since upgrading to Debian 10 (Buster): a complete freeze every few days.

As for debugging, I'm not so sure. I've posted my own question ([System occasionally crashing since dist upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541740/system-occasionally-crashing-since-dist-upgrade)) and haven't had any help yet.

My own (limited) debugging methods so far:

`sudo less /var/log/syslog | egrep -i --color error`
`sudo dmesg | egrep -i --color error`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dmesg/syslog, after a reboot try

`journalctl -p 0..3 -b -1`

This should show any severe error messages from the previous boot.